# How can I iterate through an object array and add matching values while pushing new values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

So I have two data sets.  The `mainData` being the data I want to push to and display as the main data set.

```
// data set 1
var mainData = [{name: "david", views: 2}, {name: "andrew", views: 2}];

// data set 2
var newData = [{name: "andrew", views: 4}, {name: "david", views: 4}, {name: "chris", views: 2}];
```

The second data set is new or incoming data which I want to do one of two things with.  I want to search through the main data set and see if any keys match, if so I just want to add views to the object with the same `name`.  If the `name` key doesn't match any object in the `mainData` I want to then push that object to `mainData`.

My final `mainData` should look like this:

```
[{name: "david", views: 6}, {name: "andrew", views: 6}, {name: "chris", views: 2}]
```

Notice how `david` and `andrew` now have values of 6 while `chris` did not match any objects and was simply pushed.  What is the most effiecient way of acheiving this in pure Javascript?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to empty newData during processing do:

```
while (newData.length) {
    var nd = newData.shift(), nam = nd.name, vie = nd.view;
    if (!mainData.some(function(md) {
        if (md.name === nam) {md.view += vie; return true;}
    })) mainData.push(nd);
}
```

else if the objects in newData shall stay there do

```
newData.forEach(function(nd) {
    var nam = nd.nam, vie = nd.view;
    if (!mainData.some(function(md) {
        if (md.name === nam) {md.view += vie; return true;}
    })) mainData.push(nd);
});
```

In both cases mainData.some() iterates over mainData. Its callback function checks at each step whether the name-properties are identic. If so, the view-properties are added, the callback returns true (= "matching names found") and iteration is stopped. Otherwise the callback returns nothing and iteration goes on. Since some() is inside an negated condition, mainData.push() happens only if some() does not find a match.

`Array.forEach()` and `some()` are very fast. If they are not available, you have to use `for-loops` with less efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner!